# Complex Sorting of DataTable in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, datagridview, datatable

I have a datatable, the first five columns of which contain static information, and the rest of which are dynamically built based on some user selections. The dynamic columns are actually groups of 3 columns - such as:

1. Shop Name (user will enter quantity in this column)
2. Shop Sale
3. Shop Stock

These would appear per row, of course, but each user might select a different set of 3 columns to display.

The above already works. The requirement I am trying to solve for now is to SORT the grid based on the **Shop Sale** column, keeping the sets of three intact. As an example, the shop with most sales will come left-most, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue, I sorted shops list at an earlier stage, using datatable.defaultview.sort method, issue resolved.